# Iterating over dictionary containing array objects in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

So I'm trying to iterate over a dictionary object in python and all I'm getting is list out of index error. Here is what my list looks like -

```
test_list = {"1":[{"1":[{"a":"100","b":"200"}],"2":[{"a":"300","b":"400"}]}]}
```

And here is the code -

```
for counter in range(len(test_list)):
            print test_list['1'][counter]
```

Any idea why am I getting that error?

EDIT: I want to access all of a & b elements in test_list

Comment: In which dictionary?  You have two dictionaries there, each with an a and b element.

Comment: I want to access a and b element of both the dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't raise an error for me.  If you want the first a and b elements, you would need:

```
for key, val in test_list['1'][0]['1'][0].items():
    print key, val
```

Needless to say, that is rather convoluted.  What you have is a dictionary in a list in a dictionary in a list in a dictionary.  Why are you using this data structure?  There is almost certainly a simpler way to represent your data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try it. Unfortunately, this is what I've got as data from some third party. It's large dictionary of json responses, so I have to deal with its convoluted structure

Comment: Yep it worked. If I want to access other items then I have to slightly modify this block. I've added the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
for k,v in test_list.items():
    print v[0]['1']
```

Ok, maybe this help:

```
for c in test_list:
    for v in test_list[c]:
            print v['1']
            print v['2']
```

Comment: If I type print v[0]['2'] then it will again throw an error. Where as if I have v[0]['1'] it will only give me first dictionary (within dictionary test_list)

Answer (score 1):

```
    python 3.2

    t = {"1":[{"1":[{"a":"100","b":"200"}],"2":[{"a":"300","b":"400"}]}]}
    res=[v["a"] for x in t.values() for p in x for y in p.values() for v in y] # values for a
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested dicts within lists, awesome.

I did the following, which can be modified to access the items needed.

```
In [21]: inside_dict = test_list['1'][0]

In [22]: for key,val in inside_dict.items():
    print '{} contains'.format(key)
    for key2, val2 in val[0].items():
        print '\t{}: {}'.format(key2, val2)
Out[22]:
1 contains
        a: 100
        b: 200
2 contains
        a: 300
        b: 400
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your answer. Yea, the data structure is kinda convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer

```
for key, val in test_list['1'][0].items():
    print key, val[0]['a']
    print key, val[0]['b']
```